# Why can't I ping any computers on the same hub?

Tags: networking, ip, hub

I'm having some interesting problems pinging machines, with the end goal to have Computer B SSH into Computer C.  The specific error message I get from `ping` is "Destination Host Unreachable", and `ssh` returns "No Route To Host".
To start, the following is my network topology:

```
Router (192.168.1.1)
   |
   |---- Computer A (192.168.1.2)
   |
   |---- Hub
          |
          |---- Computer B (192.168.1.3)
          |
          |---- Computer C (192.168.1.4)
```

Computer A is able to ping both Computers B and C, and vice-versa.  However, Computer B cannot ping Computer C, and vice-versa.  The IP addresses are shown above, and the network configuration for each machine is:

```
Gateway - 192.168.1.1
Netmask - 255.255.255.0
```

Why am I unable to have Computer B communicate with Computer C in this setup?

Comment: If you remove/replace the hub does the problem go away? Hubs are dumb (as in they don't do much) so I can't imagine it would be anything other than a bad hub if the problem goes away.

Comment: @r.tanner.f due to physical limitations, the hub has to stay.  I do not believe the hub is bad, since all computers have full internet connectivity, and are able to access other machines on the network (i.e. Comp. B can see Comp. A).

Comment: Firewall rules? (You can test it with the router unplugged and the FW temporarily turned off).   Does it change if you change the cabling so that computer A and C are on the hub? (or A and B).

Comment: @Hennes I have ruled out all factors related to the computers, as I've physically interchanged the computers and get the same result irregardless of the machine.  Right now, A can ping C.  If I move A to the hub, I cannot ping C anymore.

Comment: As a sanity check, is there any way for me to force packets to be directed to the default gateway, even though Comp. B/C lie in the same subnet?

Comment: Something like `route add 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1 1 Interface` (or route add -host). The syntax depends on the used OS. But setting a direct route to the gateway is possible.

Comment: This "Hub", is it actually a switch? What's the make and model?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick no, it is indeed a hub.  I don't have the make and model handy - at this point, I'm just going to run to the store and replace it with a switch (it's about time I did it regardless).  I'll give an update when I make the switch (lol pun).

Comment: @r.tanner.f looks like you were right, appears to be a bad hub.  Just replaced it with a switch, and everything's working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hub is not a Hub, it is a switch with different segment VLANs configured on each interface. Router is stripping the 8021Q tags and allowing routed communication back across to a single vlan.

If the router were replaced with a switch you wouldn't see the communication to and from A - B,  A- C.

The reason why you are getting destination unreachable is because there is no ip on that vlan segment the ip of B on C's segment.

Hubs are multi-port repeaters. There is no way a simple hub can block this communication, this is not a hub but a misconfigured switch.

-- or Hub is busted.. lol.

Comment: And looks like you (and firstly, [r.tanner.f](http://superuser.com/users/146694/r-tanner-f)) were right.  I replaced the hub with a switch, and was instantly able to connect between Computers B and C.  For this reason, I'm going to assume that the hub was infact broken.

Comment: That's a weird one. I've never heard of a hub half breaking... Always thought they'd either be rock solid or just dead. Have to keep this in mind in the future.